# Injective acton of an Chevalley generator of $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ on non-intergral weight module

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have a problem as follows.

Let $E_{i,j}\in M_2(\mathbb{C})$ be the elementary matrix and $\mathfrak{g}:=\mathfrak{sl}(2) = \{  A \in M_2({\mathbb{C}})| tr(A) =0 \}$  the special linear Lie algebra. Fix $\mathfrak{h}=\mathbb{C}(E_{11} - E_{22})$ the standard Cartan sub-algebra of $\mathfrak{g}$, and $\{\alpha\}$ the only simple root of $\mathfrak{g}$ . Recall that there is a standard bilinear form $<,>$ on $\mathfrak{h}^*$. Let $V$ be a weight $\mathfrak{g}$-module (i.e. a $\mathfrak{g}$-module which is semi-simple over $\mathfrak{h}$.)

$\bf My$ $\bf Question:$ Is it true that if every weight $\mu$ of $V$ satisfies that $<\mu, \alpha'> \notin \mathbb{Z}$. ($\alpha':=2\alpha/<\alpha,\alpha>$ the co-root) then $E_{21}$ acts as one-to-one linear operator on $V$? Thank you very much!

Comment: Hmm, certainly this seems to hold with the further restriction that the module be in $\mathcal{O}$. But I think  it might fail without that.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! How can we prove this in the case $V\in \mathcal{O}$?

Comment: Restrict the action to the socle and check that the claim holds for simple modules (which can be described in general).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that shows how this fails outside category $\mathcal{O}$ (I will give a general example that may be good to keep in mind for other Lie algebras as well).

Let $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{n}^-\oplus \mathfrak{h}\oplus\mathfrak{n}^+$ be the usual decomposition and set $\mathfrak{b^-} = \mathfrak{n}^-\oplus\mathfrak{h}$ be the opposite of the usual Borel subalgebra.

For $\lambda\in \mathfrak{h}^*$, we define an "opposite" Verma module (not to be confused with a dual Verma module) by $$W(\lambda) = U(\mathfrak{g})\otimes_{U(\mathfrak{b}^-)}\lambda$$ where $\lambda$ is a $\mathfrak{b}^-$-module by letting $\mathfrak{h}$ act via $\lambda$ and $\mathfrak{n}^-$ act as $0$.

An easy argument shows that $\mathfrak{n}^-$ acts locally nilpotently on $W(\lambda)$.

It is now easy to check that in the case of $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$, if $\lambda$ is not integral then the same holds for all weights of $W(\lambda)$ (in fact, the weights of $W(\lambda)$ are precisely those of the form $\lambda + 2k$ for some $k\geq 0$). In particular, we see that $W(\lambda)$ satisfies the conditions, but since $E_{21}$ is in $\mathfrak{n}^-$ it acts locally nilpotently and thus it cannot act as an injective operator.

The "easy arguments" mentioned above are simply the same as the ones for the usual Verma modules, with the roles of $\mathfrak{n}^+$ and $\mathfrak{n}^-$ switched.

Comment: This is a nice example! Thank you very much!

Comment: Motivated by your example above I was wondering whether the original result is true if we give the condition: $E_{12}$ act locally nilpotent on $V$? The reason is that: If $E_{21}\cdot v_{\mu} =0 $ for some weight vector $v:=v_{\mu}$ of $V$. Then we consider the $\ell \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $w:=E_{12}^{\ell} \cdot v \neq 0$ but $E_{12}^{\ell+1}\cdot v =0$. Therefore we obtain a non-zero homomorphism from the Verma $\text{Ind}_{\mathfrak{b}^+}^{\mathfrak{g}}\mathbb{C}_{\mu}$ to $U(\mathfrak{g})\cdot w$. Since this Verma is simple the result follows. Is this argument correct? Thank you!

Comment: @Khako Yes, that is a nice way to do it (a bit simpler than my proof in the category $\mathcal{O}$ case in fact). Alternatively, since we already knew it held for category $\mathcal{O}$, we could just note that the module not being finitely generated could not change this, since being injective is a local property for morphisms of modules.